# get folder name with find ... -name command in bash

Tags: bash, find

Trying to get name of venv folder for activating it in bash script located inside the project. Because someone could use for venv another name like 'someones_env'

```
projectdir=$(cd ../../ && pwd)
echo "$(dirname "$projectdir")"

venvdir=$(find "$(dirname "$projectdir")" -name '*env')
echo "$(dirname "$venvdir")"

source "$(dirname "$venvdir")"/bin/activate
```

but $venvdir becomes the same as $projectdir instead of 'someones_env'

what am i doing wrong?
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The directory of the `*env` folder is the project directory, that's why `dirname "$venvdir"` becomes the same as the project directory. Without `dirname` it should work.

Also, the directory of `../../` is `../../../`, this might also be giving you some issues. If you are already in a directory, there's no need to use `dirname`. `dirname` calculates the parent directory.